# QScrollArea, скролл графика

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside6, qscrollarea, qchartview

Есть график, довольно большой по оси **`X`**. Надо отображать в окошке только его часть, остальное должно быть прокручиваемой ползунком в QScrollArea.

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtCharts import *
import pandas as pd
import sys


# Функция чтения данных
def read_csv_file( file, n):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    col = df.loc[:, n]
    return col.tolist()


# Скролл обёртка для графика
class ScrollChartClass(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, chart):
        super().__init__()
        self.chart = chart
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.sizePolicy()
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.chart)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.scroll)
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)
        return


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent: QObject = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.filename = "example_csv_file.csv"
        self.resize(1000, 250)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        # достали данные
        self.data1_1 = read_csv_file(self.filename, 'plan_mes')
        self.data1_2 = read_csv_file(self.filename, 'plan_prj')
        seriesData1_1 = QLineSeries()
        seriesData1_2 = QLineSeries()
        # одинаковое число строк в файле => для всех графиков одинаковая длина OX
        for x in range(len(self.data1_1)):
            seriesData1_1.append(QPointF(x, self.data1_1[x]))
            seriesData1_1.setColor(QColor("green"))
            seriesData1_1.setName('plan_mes')
            seriesData1_2.append(QPointF(x, self.data1_2[x]))
            seriesData1_2.setColor(QColor("red"))
            seriesData1_2.setName('plan_prj')

        x_axis = QValueAxis()
        x_axis.setRange(0.0, len(self.data1_1))
        y_axis = QValueAxis()
        y_axis.setRange(min(self.data1_1), max(self.data1_1))

        chartModel = QChart()
        chartModel.layout().setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)  #
        chartModel.addSeries(seriesData1_1)
        chartModel.addSeries(seriesData1_2)
        chartModel.createDefaultAxes()

        windowLayout = QGridLayout()         # было бы достаточно QHBoxLayout()
        view = QChartView(chartModel)
        view.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        scroll_chart_class = ScrollChartClass(view)
        windowLayout.addWidget(scroll_chart_class, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(windowLayout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication()
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

График построен по данным из игрушечного файла, там сейчас 200 строк, т.е. 200 значений по оси **`X`**. Сейчас все эти 200 строк отображаются одновременно. 
Мне надо видеть, например, 50 из них, остальное должно быть под скроллом.

Первая мысль - покрутить настройки `x_axis.setRange`, но нет, не получается.

Пример сделан в *PySide*, это тот же *PyQt*, пусть никого не смущает.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtCharts import *
import pandas as pd
import sys



datafile = "example_csv_file.csv"


def read_csv_file( file, n):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    col = df.iloc[:, n]
    return col.values.tolist()

# класс скрола
class ScrollChartClass(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, chart):
        super().__init__()
        self.chart = chart
        self.init_UI()
        self.len_of_file = 0

    def init_UI(self):
        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(False)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.chart)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.scroll)
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)
        return

# класс графика
class ChartClass(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, file, n):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(10000, 200)
        self.file = file
        self.n = n
        self.init_UI()
        self.current_position = 0

    def init_UI(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        view = self.create_linechart(self.file, self.n)
        layout.addWidget(view)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def create_linechart(self, file, n):
        seriesData1, seriesData2 = QLineSeries(), QLineSeries()
        data1 = read_csv_file(file, 1)
        data2 = read_csv_file(file, 1)
        seriesData1.setColor(QColor("green"))
        seriesData2.setColor(QColor("red"))
        for x in range(len(data1)):
            seriesData1.append(QPointF(x, data1[x]))
            seriesData2.append(QPointF(x, data2[x]))
        chart = QChart()
        chart.legend().setVisible(False)
        chart.addSeries(seriesData1)
        chart.addSeries(seriesData2)
        chart.createDefaultAxes()
        view = QChartView(chart)
        view.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        chartview = QChartView(chart)
        return chartview


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    chart = ChartClass(datafile, 1)
    scroll = ScrollChartClass(chart)
    scroll.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Sorry, я не могу проверить ваш ответ, потому что он как и пример в вопрос -не воспроизводимый. Пожалуйста, прокомментируйте что вы сделали такого, что вы приняли ваш ответ как правильный.

Comment: Что значит 'невоспроизводимый'? Оба примера работающие, только что у себя проверил.

Comment: 'Что сделал чтобы принять ответ как правильный'. Я решил этот вопрос, и вернулся в топик чтобы разместить правильное решение. Что именно сделал уже не помню, тратить время на сравнение кода не готов. К чему эти вопросы? Или вы расстроились что принят не ваш ответ? Так и скажите, поставлю галочку.

Comment: Говорю, мне расстраиваться нечего, я в свое удовольствие, чем могу, тем и помогаю сообществу. А вы написали код, который проверить нельзя и говорите, что этот код правильный без каких-либо комментариев или пометок в коде. Вы можете предположить, что ответ на ваш вопрос кому-то из пользователей сообщества, может быть интересен? Если нет, то я вам сочувствую. The END.

Comment: Ещё раз: что значит 'код, который проверить нельзя'? Данных я действительно не предоствавил, но помимо этого что не так? У вас код не заводится?

Answer (score 1):

> PySide6.QtGui.QWindow.[**setMinimumWidth**](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtGui/QWindow.html#PySide6.QtGui.PySide6.QtGui.QWindow.setMinimumWidth)(w)
>
> содержит минимальную ширину виджета в пикселях.

```
'''
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtCharts import *                                  # PySide6 QtCharts
import pandas as pd
'''
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtChart import *                                     # PyQt5 QtChart


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt скролл графика")
        self.resize(1100, 500)                                           

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        
        self.scroll_area = QScrollArea()                         
        self.scroll_area.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
#        self.scroll_area.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll_container = QWidget()
        self.scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.scroll_container)
        
        self.scroll_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.scroll_container)
        self.scroll_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        
        self.plot_button = QPushButton("Add plot")
        self.plot_button.clicked.connect(self.plot)
        
        windowLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)    
        windowLayout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)
        windowLayout.addWidget(self.plot_button)

    def plot(self):
        container = QWidget()                                          # +++
        lay = QVBoxLayout(container)                                   # +++
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)                             # +++
        
        self.scroll_layout.addWidget(container)                        # +++
        container.setMinimumWidth(1000)                                # !!! +++ <----
        
        x = ['2018-07-01 13:06:38', '2018-07-01 12:46:38', 
             '2018-07-01 12:36:38', '2018-07-01 12:26:38', 
             '2018-07-01 12:16:38', '2018-07-01 12:06:38', 
             '2018-07-01 11:56:38', '2018-07-01 11:46:38', 
             '2018-07-01 11:36:38', '2018-07-01 11:26:38', 
             '2018-07-01 10:56:38', '2018-07-01 10:46:38', 
             '2018-07-01 10:36:38'] 
        y = [23.5, 20.8, 28.0, 28.1, 28.0, 27.8, 27.3, 27.2, 
             25.7, 24.7, 25.0, 25.0, 24.9]

        num_ticks = 10
        time_len  = 'Time'

        series = QLineSeries()
        for t, val in zip(x, y):
            series.append(QDateTime.fromString(
                t, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").toMSecsSinceEpoch(), val)
        chart = QChart()
        chart.addSeries(series)
        font = QFont("Sans Serif", )
        font.setPixelSize(18)
        chart.setTitleFont(font)

        chart.setTitle("Температура в градусах Цельсия для устройства:")
        chart.setAnimationOptions(QChart.SeriesAnimations)

        palette = QPalette()
        palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, Qt.red)
        chart.setPalette(palette)

        backgroundGradient = QLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400)
        backgroundGradient.setColorAt(0.0, QColor('#50a1dc'))
        backgroundGradient.setColorAt(1.0, QColor('#00a1de'))
        chart.setBackgroundBrush(backgroundGradient)

        plotAreaGradient = QLinearGradient(0, 100, 0, 400)
        plotAreaGradient.setColorAt(0.0, QColor('#f1f1f1'))
        plotAreaGradient.setColorAt(1.0, QColor('#ffffff'))
        chart.setPlotAreaBackgroundBrush(plotAreaGradient)
        chart.setPlotAreaBackgroundVisible(True)

        axisX = QDateTimeAxis()
        axisX.setTickCount(num_ticks)
        axisX.setFormat("dd-MM HH:mm")
        axisX.setTitleText(time_len)
        axisY = QValueAxis()
        axisY.setLabelFormat("%i")
        axisY.setTitleText("Temperature C")
        Lfont = QFont("Sans Serif")
        Lfont.setPixelSize(16)
        axisX.setLabelsFont(Lfont)
        axisY.setLabelsFont(Lfont)
        axisPen = QPen(QColor('#151512'))
        axisPen.setWidth(2)
        axisX.setLinePen(axisPen)
        axisY.setLinePen(axisPen)

        axisBrush = QBrush(QColor('#ffffff'))
        axisX.setLabelsBrush(axisBrush)
        axisY.setLabelsBrush(axisBrush)
        axisX.setGridLineVisible(True)
        axisY.setGridLineVisible(True)
        axisY.setShadesBrush(QBrush(QColor('#ffffff')))
        # axisX.setShadesBrush(QBrush(QColor('#ffffff')))
        axisY.setShadesVisible(True)
        chart.addAxis(axisX, Qt.AlignBottom)
        series.attachAxis(axisX)
        axisX.setLabelsAngle(-90)    

        chart.addAxis(axisY, Qt.AlignLeft)
        series.attachAxis(axisY)

        chartView = QChartView(chart)
        chartView.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        chart.axisY(series).setRange(min(y)-5, max(y)+5)
        chart.legend().setVisible(False)
        
        lay.addWidget(chartView)                                         # !!! +++
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]